# How to send/receive data in Extended data mode in BLE?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command

I have been working with BLE and I am using NINA-B112 BLE module. Now the requirement is to use data mode and execute AT commands[(Extended data mode)](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/ExtendedDataMode_ProtocolSpec_%28UBX-14044126%29.pdf) simulteneously. If possible, provide me a sample code for NINA-B112's Extended data mode in c.

I'm able to push the module into command mode(can send AT commands), data mode(can send/receive data), EDM(no idea, so none) individually through ATO commands.

Comment: So are you or are you not able to enter EDM? "No idea so none" doesn't really parse. Isn't it just "ATO2", what response do you get? This is a bit vague/too broad.

Comment: i am able to enter the extended data mode. But i need to know "How to send/receive data in Extended data mode in BLE and to run AT commands simultaneously"

Comment: no idea, so none - means iam unable to do anything in EDM such as send/receive data in Extended data mode, send AT commands.

Comment: Well did you read the U-blox spec and try to implement it? It clearly says how AT commands and data are packaged differently in the EDM.

Comment: I have read, but i am not getting HOW TO SEND commands to the module. If possible provide me a sample code :)